# simplify this python generation

Tags: python, lambda, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, generator

I am new to python. Is there a way to simplify this:

```
def getDivs():
    divs = soup.findAll(name = "div", attrs = {"class" : "resultCell"}, recursive = True)
    for div in divs:
        h2 = div.find("h2")
        a = h2.find("a")
        href = a["href"]
        yield (href)

divs = list(getDivs())
```

I feel I should be able to create an anonymous function instead of getDivs. Something like (pseudocode):

```
divs = 

  [
     divs = soup.findAll(name = "div", attrs = {"class" : "resultCell"}, recursive = True)
     for div in divs:
        h2 = div.find("h2")
        a = h2.find("a")
        href = a["href"]
        yield (href)
  ]
```

Thanks

Comment: use `lxml` and `xpath` :P should get you a oneliner...

Answer (score 3):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
divs = [ div.find("h2").find("a")["href"]
           for div in soup.findAll(name = "div",
                                   attrs = {"class" : "resultCell"},
                                   recursive = True) ]
```

But using proper XML parsing tools is a better idea.

Comment: you removed the inner "divs" variable. I am not sure this is general enough. For example, in your solution, how many times is soup.findAll() evaluated?

Comment: @seguso `soup.findAll()` would be evaluated just as many times as it is in your code. The above code is equivalent to your code.

Comment: thanks.

is there some solution that allows to keep the intermediate variables h2, a, href? something like list(lambda(...)) ?

Comment: Unlikely. A lambda expression cannot contain arbitrary code; its body must be single expression, not a series of statements.